# Is there a way to automatically attach emails to an entry

Tags: ee2, control-panel, email

I'm exploring whether it's possible to attach an email that's sent to a specific address to a particular entry.

I use a project management system called Workflow Max and for each project on the system you get a unique email address. If you CC your client emails to that address they get stored on the system.

I'm building a client area for a client and would like a way to create a similar feature for their client area. In other words, somehow create a unique email address for each entry in the system. When an email is CC'd to that address it's stored in a particular field (or even as a new entry) in EE.

Anyone know where to start with this?

Any help appreciated,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if there's an existing add-on which can do this, there is surely not.

This will have to be all custom. On the EE end, you'll need to use some [extension hooks](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extension_hooks/index.html) for when entries are created/updated to create the email addresses and store them, then also a module with a CSRF-exempt action which can be called by whatever is processing the emails to update a field or what have you.

The biggest hurdle will be finding a service which can act as your email relay that allows the creation of custom email addresses via an API of some kind. I'm not aware of one myself, but surely it exists.